# ajax & load are not working togeher

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I want to check each time user access when page loading, `sessions.php` is working and return true or false but load is not working with ajax...

```
var section = $("#header a");
section.on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/particley/global/post/sessions.php",

        success: function(html) {
            if (html == 'true') {

                $('#load').load(section.id + ' #load');
                window.history.pushState(this.id, this.id, this.id);

                if (this.id == '/p/sign-out') {
                    window.location.assign("/p");
                }

            } else {
                window.location.assign("/p/sign-out");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Uh but the event is triggering `on click` and not `on load` in your current code

Comment: I would expect `$('#load').load(this.id` or `$('#load').load(section.attr("id")`

Comment: load working alone with no problem

Comment: Then what IS the problem?

Comment: page not loading with in $.ajax...

Comment: What part of your code doesn't work? Please be more specific

Comment: $('#load').load(section.id + ' #load') returns empty page but when it is not in success: function(html) working well...

Comment: $('#load').load(section.id + ' #load') returns empty page but when it is not in success: function(html) working well...

Comment: jQuery objects do not have `.id` - you need to do `section.attr("id")` or this.id

Answer (score 1):

```
var section = $("#header a");
section.click(function(){
    $('#load').load(this.id + ' #load', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/particley/global/post/sessions.php",
            success: function(html) 
            {

                if (html != 'true') {
                    window.location.assign("/p/sign-out");
                } 
            }

        });
    }); 
    window.history.pushState(this.id, this.id, this.id);
    if (this.id == '/p/sign-out') {
        window.location.assign("/p/sign-out");
    }
});
```

Comment: it works for me, $(#header a"); is not a single element... so i need to use "this.id" if i dont.. it does not work and no console error...

Comment: But I told you this. There is no section.id when section is a jQuery object or collection

Answer (score 0):

for this line

```
 $('#load').load(section.id + ' #load');
```

did you mean:

```
 $('#load').load(section.attr("id")  + ' #load');
```

to retrieve the attribute id ?

2 cents ;)

Comment: now i understand the problem... load working with only this.id when i change it to section.id or section.attr('id'); it is not working...

Comment: "not working" is not a useful statement. What is not working? Console error? You have not provided enough information in your code to help us help you. Also this answer is a copy of my comment one hour ago

Comment: Sorry @mplungjan, did not check out your answer ;) by the way i reconstruct the estimated html and ajax call, and it works fine for me ...